# PLC / Scada education requirements.

Tags: education

I'm looking for some advice on what study of engineering I should pursue. I want to be a PLC / SCADA programmer, but with all these engineering titles I am lost on what to even look for. I was thinking electrical engineering and then take some smaller programming courses. If anybody has any experience in the field or knows anybody and can guide me in the right direction it will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.